# Data argument not used by format string - Outputting long

Tags: c, timer, arguments, real-time, clock

Okay, this is a C program... and I get this issue even though I have it properly placed. long ms and in the print I have "l". Now, x is a global int variable that user enters through commandline argument and x then atoi() the argument.

This issue takes place in a function. I am wondering if I maybe am outputting it wrong or not. Should I maybe typecast when setting int x to this long ms variable before trying to output it or what? I am confused and trying to output miliseconds.

```
    struct timespec now;
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
 long ms;
 x = ms;
 ms = round(now.tv_nsec / 1.0e6);

 fprintf(stdout, "l: flip\n", ms);
```

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, "l: flip\n", ms);` doesn't look right. You forgot to add a format specifier `%ld`

Comment: warning: invalid conversion specifier ':'
      [-Wformat-invalid-specifier]
 fprintf(stdout, "%l: flip\n", ms);

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives an issue like inversion conversion specifier.

Comment: Use `%ld` not `%l`

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, hm so at least now it is giving me some numbers... Now I gotta make it actually work better. Great! So this type-casting issue is solved. Thanks guys! I can continue working to finish my program. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've commented your code with the things I see.

```
struct timespec now;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
long ms;
x = ms;  
// <== this is assigning a variable 'ms' to the variable 'x'
// however, the variable 'ms' is not initialized 
// this will cause the compiler to raise a warning message
// about using an uninitialized variable
// this is (for the above reason) undefined behavior

ms = round(now.tv_nsec / 1.0e6); 
// <-- initialized the variable 'ms'
// but it is too late for the prior statement
// AND the compiler will not be happy about the 'implied' 
// conversion from the returned type from 'round()' 
// which is 'double' to the type 'long int' of the variable 'ms'
// The compiler will be happy if the line is written like this:
ms = (long int)round( now.tv_nsec / 1.0e6 );


fprintf(stdout, "l: flip\n", ms); 
// <-- will cause the compiler to complain, as you already know
```

if instead the code were:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%l: flip\n", ms); 
// <-- will also cause the compiler to complain about a invalid format specifier
```

if instead, the code were to use a valid format specifier that matches the 'type' of the variable 'ms' (long int)

```
fprintf(stdout, "%ld: flip\n", ms); 
// <-- now compiler happy
```

the format specifier '%ld' means a 'long integer'

The man page for `fprintf()` (or `printf()`) tells you about all the valid format specifiers available and what they do.